# Where are the Properties gone ? I did Properties.Resources but properties not exist

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the code in my class i have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace Magnifier20070401
{
    public partial class MagnifierForm : Form
    {
        public MagnifierForm(Configuration configuration, Point startPoint)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //--- My Init ---
            mConfiguration = configuration;
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;

            ShowInTaskbar = mConfiguration.ShowInTaskbar;
            TopMost = mConfiguration.TopMostWindow;
            Width = mConfiguration.MagnifierWidth;
            Height = mConfiguration.MagnifierHeight;

            // Make the window (the form) circular
            GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
            gp.AddEllipse(ClientRectangle);
            Region = new Region(gp);

            mImageMagnifier = Properties.Resources.magnifierGlass;
```

On the Properties im getting: Error 1   The name 'Properties' does not exist in the current context

I added this Form as Existing item to my project and im getting an error on this Properties.
And i have the magnifierGlass image in the Resources.

Comment: maybe the wrong namespace?

Answer (score 0):

Found it needed to add my project name before the properties:

```
mImageMagnifier = ScreenVideoRecorder.Properties.Resources.magnifierGlass;
```

Now it's working thanks.