# How do I know what my project's name is?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This is probably a very newbie question, but how can I tell what my project's name is?  I've read that the project name is not the same as the assembly name.

Comment: Why do you need to know this name?

Comment: Your project's name is whatever you have given it.

Comment: So that I can use `.Properties.Resources` as shown in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16016561/977472

Comment: @BartFriederichs, presumably so, but now I'm trying to figure it out after the fact.

Comment: @Joe In that case, you don't want to know the project name, you want to know the default namespace. This is shown in the project settings window.

Comment: Assuming, of course, that you've not changed it since. To find the namespace for your properties as it is now, open Solution Explorer and look for the Resources.Designer.resx file. If you open it, the namespace at the top is your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's what shows in the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio. You can change the name of the .csproj file, but the project name will remain the same. In order to change it, use either VS or change the contents of the .csproj file.

Answer (score 2):

In your `csproj` file:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyName>SOME NAME OF YOUR CHOOSING</AssemblyName>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

This does not *have* to match the `csproj` file name for your project, but it typically does. It will determine the name of the `exe` or `dll` file you build.

You can change it through Visual Studio:

1. right-click your project in the Solution Explorer
2. click Properties in the drop-down list
3. go to the Application tab
4. change the "Assembly name" field

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `Application.ProductName`?

Comment: I'm not sure what that is, and the name `Application` isn't coming up when I type it.  Is there a `using` I need?

Comment: Weird, [it works for me](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.aspx).
Not sure if this is what you're looking for though.

Comment: This would only work for a WinForm application, and this property is retrieved from the Assembly manifest which is not the same as the Project's name.

Comment: @JaceRhea Oh, that's why... Thank you for pointing that out!